# Set start and end time for embedded iframe video

Tags: iframe, video, parameters, embed

I would like to embed a video (www.bnn.ca/Video/player.aspx?vid=564163) onto my site and specify start and end times for playback. Similar to the way youtube allows this through its start and end parameters. Here's the embed code:

`<iframe src="https://bmplayer-a.akamaihd.net/shareable/embedssl.html?dc=bnn_web&cid=564163&col=766&w=480&h=270&pl=0&plh=0&adSite=ctv.bnn&adZone=shows/marketcall&omniAcct=ctvgmtvebnndesktop,ctvgmglobal&section=video - hub&site=bnn&shareUrl=&v7=player&v8=&v9=&v10=" width="480" height="270" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" ></iframe>`

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If the site didn't give you that option, you can do nothing !

Comment: Was beginning to think that... thanks for your response